# DataGridView how to check which row is selected?

Tags: powershell, datagridview

Quite simple but i'm new at DataGridView...I'm in powershell studio but the properties are probably the same for C# and others…

How do you, on a button click event check which row is selected? I'm trying `$datagridview1.SelectedRows.Contains...` and `$datagridview1.SelectedRows.Equals..` but can't get it to work. What is the proper way of approching this?

Thanks

```
$form1_Load={
    $infoposte = $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Information Poste", "Fourni plus d'une vingtaine d'information sur un poste")
    $rerunts = $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Re-Run TS", "Permet de relancer une task sequence qui a déjà été exécutée sur un poste")
    $gestiontrousse = $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Gestion Trousse", "Permet l'ajout, retrait, complete d'une trousse sur un poste distant (via le compte SYSTEM, équivalent de SCCM")
    $controleadistancevnc = $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Contrôle à distance VNC", "Outil de prise de contrôle à distance d'un poste")
    msg * TEST
}



$buttonOK_Click={
    if ($datagridview1.SelectedRows.Equals($infoposte))
    {
    msg * TEST  
    }

}
```

EDIT : I have got it working like this, but is it the optimal way? :

```
$formMenuOutilsDPFL_Load={
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Information Poste")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Re-Run TS")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Gestion Trousse")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Contrôle à distance VNC")

}



$buttonOK_Click = {
    $InfoPoste = $datagridview1.Rows[0]
    $ReRunTS = $datagridview1.Rows[1]
    $GestionTrousse = $datagridview1.Rows[2]
    $ControleDistance = $datagridview1.Rows[3]


    if ($datagridview1.SelectedRows.Contains($InfoPoste))
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
$formMenuOutilsDPFL_Load={
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Information Poste", "Fourni plus d'une vingtaine d'information sur un poste")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Re-Run TS", "Permet de relancer une task sequence qui a déjà été exécutée sur un poste")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Gestion Trousse", "Permet l'ajout, retrait, complete d'une trousse sur un poste distant (via le compte SYSTEM, équivalent de SCCM")
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add("Contrôle à distance VNC", "Outil de prise de contrôle à distance d'un poste")

}

$buttonOK_Click = {
    $datagridview1.SelectedRows | ForEach-Object {
        switch ($_.Cells[0].Value) {
            "Information Poste"        { Do-InformationPoste }
            "Re-Run TS"                { Do-ReRunTS }
            "Gestion Trousse"          { Do-GestionTrousse }
            "Contrôle à distance VNC"  { Do-VNC }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach, thanks for the input much appreciated